# including php in html code within php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
if(isset($left))
{
echo    "<button name = rightname onclick= \" disp();\">". "$left"."</button>";
}
?>
```

here disp is a php function. but i am not able to use it. can anybody say me how to overcome this problem...

Comment: No, `disp` is a JavaScript function in that context. If you meant to use `disp()` as a PHP function you would have to do a postback and check if the user clicked `rightname`.

Comment: Remove the backslashes and add dots: `".disp().">`

Answer (score 1):

The only way to run a PHP function in response to a user clicking on something in their browser, is to send an HTTP request to the server.

The simplest way to achieve this would be:

```
<a href="disp.php"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($left); ?></a>
```

You then need to write disp.php such that it includes the function you want to run, and calls it. Then you need to return an appropriate response to the browser (e.g. a page to display or a redirect (via Location) header.

You could also look at using XMLHttpRequest (probably via a third party library such as [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/connection/) or [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)) to make the HTTP request using JavaScript without the user leaving the page (Ajax). Given the amount of knowledge you *appear* to have based on your question, you might need an [introduction to JavaScript](http://wsc.opera.com/) first.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try like this

```
<?php
if(isset($left))
{
?>
    <button name ="rightname" onclick= "<?php disp();?>"><?php echo $left;?></button>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: How do you think, what is disp() function output?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't use Aston's answer, you can correct your code as follow:

```
<?php
if(isset($left))
{
echo    '<button name ="rightname" onclick= "' .  disp() . '">'. $left .'</button>';
}
?>
```

I wanted to point that you can use single quotes to make it easier to handle double-quotes inside.

Comment: OP says `disp()` is a php function.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it with BoltClock. Edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

onclick only works for javascript functions not PHP functions, that won't work.
See BoltClock's comment under your question.

One of the ways to run php in combination with javascript is using an ajax post (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). Eg:

```
    $.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
   function(data){
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });
```

And when concatenating variables with string you don't need to put the variable between double quotes, or just put the variable in the string without closing the double quotes.

```
echo    "<button name='rightname' >". $left."</button>";
```

Or (will only work when using double quotes)

```
echo    "<button name='rightname' >$left</button>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Before bothering with AJAX, would you mind me asking what the `disp()` function does? If it's something that doesn't heavily rely on server interaction (file operations, db connections), we may be able to help you port it to JS and remove the need for AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

I would write this:

```
<?php if(isset($left)) : ?>
   <button name="rightname" onclick="<?php disp(); ?>"><?php echo $left ?></button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: [Reference for alternative `if`/`endif` syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: I seriously doubt that disp() function produces valid dhtml parameter

Comment: thank u all. i cleared ma doubt.... And ya as m making a website i will still need help of you all(if any)... So be there with me....